# How to catch/correct exception in Spring ContextLoaderListener?

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring's ContextLoaderListener to initialise a web services client, but if the wsdl document is not available during the application startup then part of my application is broken and I'm not sure how to fix it. The application starts successfully, just logging a big ol' stack trace at that point. The exception is:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myWebService' defined in class path resource [spring-myapp-jaxws.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: The following WSDL exception occurred... etc.`

Couple of questions...

- Can I catch the init exception so that I can show the state of the broken component appropriately in my application?
- Can I tell Spring to try and reinitialise the myWebService bean on user request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining the bean as `lazy="true"`, so that it is not initialized if it is not referenced.

Otherwise you will have to create a proxy that makes this checks. Proxies can be created by:

- `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`
- cglib
- javassist

Comment: I considered lazily initializing the ws bean, decided against it as doesn't solve the problem - the wsdl might not be available when the user first tries to use it. Re: creating a proxy - you mean create something to wrap the web service bean to do the exception handling and try a reinitialization if the service isn't correctly inited?

Answer (score 0):

Your options appear to all boil down to the following:

1. Prevent the `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException` exception from propagating out of your control.  You will accomplish this by catching the exception somewhere in your code.
2. Note when the exception has been thrown, you will have to reattempt the call that threw the exception when the web service is called.
3. Accept that errors happen.  If the exception is thrown when the user tries to do something, you will need to inform the user that an error has happened and that they will need to try again (maybe after some reasonable time).

Here is an example:

```
public interface MyWebServiceCallingInterface
{
    String callTheWebService();
}

public class MyWebService extends something, 
implements MyWebServiceCallingInterface
{
    public MyWebService()
    throws javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
    {
        ... do stuff, maybe throw exception ...
    }

    public String callTheWebService()
    {
        ... do stuff ...
    }
}

public class MyWebServiceWrapper
implements MyWebServiceCallingInterface
{
    private MyWebService myWebService;

    public MyWebServiceWrapper()
    {
        createWebService();
    }

    public String callTheWebService()
    {
        if (myWebService == null)
        {
            createWebService();
        }

        if (myWebService != null)
        {
            return myWebService.callTheWebService();
        }
        else
        {
            ...error handling stuff...
            return ... something meaningful ...
        }

    }

    private void createWebService()
    {
        try
        {
            myWebService = new MyWebService();
        }
        catch (javax.xml.ws.webServiceException exception)
        {
            myWebService = null;
        }
    }
}
```